# HTML open link click anywhere

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I'm a mobile programmer who never developed any webpage

I've created a blank HTML page and I want to open new link when the user click or tap anywhere.

Is it possible?

Comment: There are many solutions; which one you use depends on what your page will be used for and what languages/techniques/libraries you're willing to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

that's an interesting question with many solutions. I'll post two.

**Solution 1 - use a full width anchor tag**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
            a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='#'></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2 - use javascript, and add a click event on the body**

```
<html>
    <body onclick='window.location.href="http://google.com"'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: very good solution with javascript, since it works with any div.

Comment: `Onclick` will consider as popup right? and it will get blocked by browser or pop up blocker or ad blocker?.

Comment: `Onclick` open a link in new tab or as a popup or in same tab like normal when we click a URL?

Comment: @Poonam no, it shouldn't be considered a popup. If you use `window.open()` instead with a target window, it can be treated like a popup

Comment: @kennypu what if visitor clicked on the link?. Let say the website have lot link. visitor clicked on link `facebook.com` and i am using javascript onclick for `google.com`. now the question is what will open for visitor? facebook or google or both?

Answer (score 2):

Just add an event listener to the body so that the URL opens when they click anywhere:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  window.open(url);
});
```

Comment: that's fine, but you should mention that you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using it for a mobile app, it's best to use pure JavaScript:

```
function OpenWin(){
  window.open("url");
}
window.onclick = OpenWin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for tab event-

```
 document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        alert("");
       window.open("www.google.com");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"> 
<html><head> 
<title>body onclick test</title> 
</head> 
<body onclick="window.location.href='newpage.html';"> 
<h1>onclick test</h1> 
<p>test</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you do not need the div tag but I think it looks better and would help add control for styling later. One issue you might run into is text styling which will just need a CSS styling for the text color and decoration to get rid of unwanted underlines.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href='link.com'>
            <div>
                All content
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```